# Invisible Apache redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, mod-proxy

I would like subdomain.mydomain.com to invisibly redirect to https://[myServerIP]:2083.

(There is an SSL issue here).

So far I managed to do it, but the redirection is visible and I don't want it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://[myServerIP]:2083/
```

Would it be a way to achieve the same redirection while maintaining permanently my beautiful "subdomain.mydomain.com" in the address bar?

**EDIT with the ProxyPass directive:**

I tried some variations with ProxyPass but it will still change the URL in the address bar:

```
ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com

<Location />
        ProxyPass               https://[myServerIP]:2083/
        ProxyPassReverse        https://[myServerIP]:2083/
</Location>

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://[myServerIP]:2083/
```

**EDIT2:**

It still doesn't work:

```
#non SSL
ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com

#SSL!
<Location />
        ProxyPass               https://[myServerIP]:2083/
        ProxyPassReverse        https://[myServerIP]:2083/
</Location>
```

**EDIT3:**

It now works using the `SSLProxyEngine` directive:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com

<Location />
        ProxyPass               https://[myServerIP]:2083/
        ProxyPassReverse        https://[myServerIP]:2083/
</Location>
```

I can now access my login interface (cPanel). However, once I'm logged in it doesn't redirect to the next page `subdomain.mydomain.com/cpsess5850710203/`.

Comment: You have a problem with your terminology here. What you want is not a redirect -- redirects by definition are not invisible in the way that you want. So you've asked for a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve your objective (of not changing the address bar) with a `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` directive. Eg:

```
<Location />
    ProxyPass https://[myServerIP]:2083
    ProxyPassReverse https://[myServerIP]:2083
</Location>
```

This will internally request the site and serve it to the browser.

Comment: I tried it (see my edit) but don't know how to get my result.

Comment: As @Christopher Perrin said in his comment, you'll want to remove (or comment out) the rewrite.

Comment: Still doesn't work :( I answered on @Christopher Perrin thead.

Comment: See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxyengine

Comment: Good point, forgot about the SSL proxy requirement.

Comment: Thanks @Fuzzyfelt, you solved the problem I was facing. However I now face a new problem (see my last edit)..

Comment: @GuilhemSoulas what's the error you get? You can try using Chrome's Network Trace in the Dev Tool or Firebug to help see what is being returned after you login

Comment: Mmmm.. on Chrome it generates a GET request to (try to) open cPanel but the tracing tools tells me `401 Access denied`. Anyway, if the proxy doesn't work, I'll just use a redirection and that's all.

Comment: @GuilhemSoulas You proxy request may be hitting the wrong vhost now. Ensure that your backend server responds properly when you hit: `https://[myServerIP]:2083` directly from your browser

Comment: I tried that of course. And it works normally. If I have some time, I will analyse the request to try to understand what happens when I log in. Thanks anyway for the SSLProxyEngine.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a [reverse proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse)

Comment: Thanks mate but I can't make it work (see my edit).

Comment: Of course you have to keep the rewrite away.

Comment: I tried hard but it doesn't work. Because of the fact that my subdomain is HTTP but the proxy is HTTPS. If I put a simple HTTP proxy it works well. Thanks.